# sql bulkcopy dropping and re-adding foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a script that generates the add statements to add (re-add in my case) foreign keys.

I run this script and grab the statements. After this, I run a script that will drop the foreign keys.

Once this is done, I want to run the add foreign keys statements to re-add them.

When I run my scripts in the sequence described above, it works! Once the foreign keys are dropped I can run the add statements and everything is added as expected.

However, after I grab the add statements and drop the foreign keys, I want to truncate the tables and do a bulkcopy and then re-add the foreign keys. Doing this fails though.

The error I get when I'm re-adding the foreign keys is as follows:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Order_Details_Orders". The conflict occurred in database "Northwind2", table "dbo.Orders", column 'OrderID'.

My re-add statements look like this:

```
USE Northwind2;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Categories] 
  FOREIGN KEY([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([CategoryID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Categories]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customers] 
   FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customers]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerCustomerDemo] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerCustomerDemo_Customers] 
  FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerCustomerDemo] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerCustomerDemo_Customers]

(and so on and so forth......)
```

Why does this fail? Also, why does it fail at that specific point? If i look in the database after the exception occurs, i can see that the other foreign keys were added. Is there a way around this? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have at least one orphaned record. You'll need to either use `WITH NOCHECK` or fix your data.

Comment: Yeah, what @ConradFrix said, you're not thoroughly cleaning your data which is causing integrity issues after the fact. If you delete a value that is referenced by a row in another table, don't delete the referencing row and then try to re-apply the constraints `WITH CHECK` (as you have) you'll run into this kind of conflict.